# What is source of Infrared Radiation from some solid object?

Tags: temperature, measurements, infrared-radiation

I use a Fluke infrared temperature measurement meter for various applications.  I have not thought too much about the source of that infrared radiation until recently.  Assume some solid with maybe a crystal structure or not (such as a block of wood) -- I can measure the temperature via the infrared radiation given off by the object.

What is the source of this radiation?  I mean, is it one of (or all of) the following:

1. charge acceleration (such as charged particle changing direction, striking something, being struck by something).
2. Photon given off by electron in atom changing energy levels.
3. Some other kind of source unknown to me.

If item 3 is the answer, can someone explain.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the various physical mechanisms for energy transfer to the photon during blackbody emission?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59213/)

Comment: The process you describe is called black body radiation, so your question comes down to what processes contribute to black body radiation. This is answered in the question I've linked above.

Comment: @JohnRennie thanks for the confirmation on Black Body radiation.  I should have mentioned that in my question as I had this idea that all infrared from objects is black body but I was not sure about that.