# What is the origin of blackbody radiation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

Of course I know what [black-body radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) is, like everyone else who has taken a thermal or statistical physics course. But it was recently pointed out to me that one thing that is rarely taught (including to me) is what the mechanism for the radiation is.

At the particle level, how does black-body radiation arise (which radiative process is this)? In other words, where are the photons coming from?

---

To perhaps clarify a bit further, borrowing a comment from Kevin Driscoll on an answer:

> The point of the question is that there are materials whose emission spectra are quite well described by a black-body spectrum. And yet we know that at the atomic level photon emission are caused by some quantum mechanical transitions. So, how is it that such an underlying quantum mechanical description gives rise to a black-body spectrum at everyday temperatures? What is the mechanics that causes light to be absorbed/emitted at all frequencies rather than at the discrete set we might expect from the electronic transitions in isolated atoms?

With a caveat from me:

> That's a good re-statement, though I'd caution that the description need not a priori be quantum mechanical in nature - there is radiation in classical electrodynamics.

Comment: I enjoy this type of questions searching for the fundamentals underlying accepted phenomena. As a personal note: when comparing in my mind an atom (as a system that emits/absorbs EM quanta) with an equivalent classical system, I see that the later has no way of liberating kinetic energy w/o loosing components, like the emission of photons. Apparently matter can "cool down" and rearrange charges at these scales in a way that is not explained by QED, which accepts that charges emit EM quanta, but tries not to derive it from other more fundamental assumptions.

Comment: A good question that I have asked myself in the past and never satisfactorily answered. It seems to me that calculating specifically how the thermodynamic limit is approached by a real model (in this case of absorption/emission processes) is something that no one finds interesting enough to pursue.

Comment: Do you want an explanation about thermal radiation?

Comment: [This](http://scienceblogs.com/principles/2015/05/26/crude-monte-carlo-simulation-of-light-bulb-physics/) may be of interest. It's a surprisingly interesting problem - I'm actually working on something along these lines now, though who knows if anything good will come from it. cc @KevinDriscoll

Comment: I was under the impression that the blackbody radiation is not produced only by the electron transitions in atomic orbitals, but by interactions in the crystal structure which has significantly more degrees of freedom. The thermal oscillations of many atoms in the lattice can absorb and emit photons with any energy. Is that reasoning flawed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the various physical mechanisms for energy transfer to the photon during blackbody emission?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59213/)

Comment: @mpv What crystals are there in the solar interior?

Comment: @RobJeffries Crystal was just an example for condensed matter. Plasma is still an electromagnetically interacting medium. Ions are colliding and scattering, free electrons can absorb or emit any photon via normal electromagnetic interaction. In plasma you are still not limited to a few electron transitions.

Comment: @mpv Indeed. Your original comment is appropriate in solid state physics.

Answer (score 2):

That information is not contained within the bb radiation - all that can be gleaned is an emitting area and a temperature.

In practice the radiation can have arisen from the inverse of any process where it is feasible for a photon at that frequency to be absorbed.

To actually be a blackbody emitter there must be a 100% chance that a photon (at any frequency, strictly speaking) incident on the object is absorbed. This condition ensures that there are relevant radiative processes that are capable of emitting at that frequency too, since there are straightforward proportionalities (for instance) between the [Einstein coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_coefficients) for absorption and both stimulated and spontaneous emission (the same is true of continuum processes too), and that the object reaches [detailed balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_coefficients#Detailed_balancing) at the microscopic level if it is in thermodynamic equilibrium.

To perhaps over-elaborate, if you postulated a hypothetical object that is *incapable* of emitting or absorbing light at some frequencies (e.g. a two-level atom with an Einstein spontaneous emission A coefficient approximating a delta function in frequency), you would never be able to make it physically thick enough to absorb or emit at those frequencies and it couldn't be a blackbody. However, in any real system there *is* always a tiny chance of absorption at *all* frequencies, due to natural or doppler broadening. If you did make the material optically thick at all frequencies (ie physically very, very thick) then its output *could* still approximate a blackbody.

Therefore, if you wanted to answer probabilistically then the most likely relevant emission process(es) are the inverse of whatever absorption process(es) make the blackbody object opaque to radiation at that frequency.

So for example, the visible (almost) blackbody radiation from the Sun's photosphere you obviously have all the optical atomic and ionic (and a few molecular) transitions, but they are only important at discrete frequencies. Continuum opacity is provided by free-free and bound-free absorption due to metal atoms, ions and free electrons (contributed by potassium and sodium mainly) but actually the dominant opacity source in the Sun's photosphere is photo-detachment of electrons from H$^{-}$ ions and hence the dominant emission process across the visible continuum is free-bound emission when H$^{-}$ ions form.

Comment: The information need not be encoded in the radiation, but surely the photons came from *somewhere*. Are you saying that any radiative process at all will do it? Surely there must be one (or one class, or some but not others) process at work here. For instance, I'm pretty sure that photons from a source with a BB spectrum are *not* coming from stimulated emission.

Comment: @KyleOman Of course stimulated emission plays a role in bb radiation, how would you prevent stimulated emission! In a bb emitter (or anything in thermodynamic eqm. the ratio of emission to absorption (including stimulated emission as negative absorption) equals the Planck function.

Comment: Stimulated emission to me implies line features in the spectrum, perhaps I'm wrong about this though. But more importantly in the context of my question, either the photons are being produced by some emission mechanism(s) that, because of the temperature of the BB, results in the famous spectrum, or the temperature is being imprinted into the radiation by some scattering process(es). Which emission mechanism(s) or scattering process(es)?

Comment: @KyleOman you are way off. BB radiation represents a detailed balance between all emission and absorption processes. Scattering just increases the effective optical depth and makes it more likely that an object would absorb everything incident upon it. Further edit.

Comment: I think this answer misses the point a bit. Of course since we're doing thermodynamics the details of the absorption/emission process shouldn't matter because the result is supposed to be universal. But that's looking at things from the wrong direction for the purpose of this question.

Comment: The point of the question is that there are materials whose emission spectra are quite well described by a blackbody spectrum. And yet we know that at the atomic level photon emission are caused by some quantum mechanical transitions. So, how is it that such an underlying quantum mechanical description gives rise to a blackbody spectrum at everyday temperatures? What is the mechanics that causes light to be absorbed/emitted at all frequencies rather than at the discrete set we might expect from the electronic transitions in isolated atoms?

Comment: @KevinDriscoll that's a good re-statement, though I'd caution that the description need not *a priori* be quantum mechanical in nature - there is radiation in classical electrodynamics.

Comment: @KevinDriscoll A (hypothetical) material that has an emission coefficient consisting of delta functions at various frequencies *cannot* be a blackbody because it would be transparent outwith those frequencies. In practice there is always some probability of emission at all frequencies; for a bb you just need to arrange for it to be (optically) thick enough to be in eqm.