# Can chemical reaction cause radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation

I have been wondering that some chemical reaction will lead to temperature increasing,what form of the energy is?Does the heat come from quantum state tansition and the photons released?If so,how does the radiation energy changed into heat?

Comment: If a chemical reaction produces heat, then the temperature of the solution increases. The energy released from radiation is typically modeled as blackbody radiation. Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59213/what-are-the-various-physical-mechanisms-for-energy-transfer-to-the-photon-durin

Comment: Combustion is a chemical reaction and it can produce visible and infrared light (e.g., fire), both of which are forms of radiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy that is released from molecules takes two forms:
1.) heat - the atomic nuclei of the molecules start vibrating faster.
2.) radiation - photons released from the breaking and forming of chemical bonds.

The photons that are released either make their way to the surface of the container (and are released as electromagnetic radiation, i.e. light), or they are reabsorbed by the neighboring chemicals, and get dedicated into increasing the vibration rate of the atomic nuclei - heat again.

Within your question, you asked if the energy comes from quantum state transitions.  Yes, it does.

Hope this helps.