# Do ionized salt solutions produce electromagnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, ions

When there is a solution  ions of both negatively and positively charged ions, is there an electromagnetic field due to Brownian motion of ions? Do oppositely charged ions mutually cancel out their electromagnetic fields?

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic fields are light, i.e. electromagnetic waves composed out of zillions of photons.

If you mean *are there electric fields due to the ions* the answer is yes. But spill over electric fields exist in all matter, and are responsible for [black body radiation,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html)  the changes in the electric fields due to vibrational and rotational states generate part of the black body radiation (see answers and  a [list here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59213/what-are-the-various-physical-mechanisms-for-energy-transfer-to-the-photon-durin) ,). Any ions present in great number will bias the black body spectrum towards higher frequency radiation as their fields are much stronger than the neutral atom/molecule spill over fields.

Comment: Yes. The "bias" is then an expression of Kirchhoff's law that emissivity equals absorption.