# What actually causes blackbody radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

I've spent a fair bit of time reading up on answers detailing exactly how blackbody radiation is created but I have seen two different explanations for how it is created.

1. The Kinetic Energy (KE) of the atoms causes them to move and collide with each other. This process causes acceleration and deacceleration of charges thus producing electromagnetic radiation.
2. The atoms bumping around somehow smash electrons of other atoms into higher energy states and when they fall down they produce quantised photons.

Could someone please clarify for me which of the two is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the various physical mechanisms for energy transfer to the photon during blackbody emission?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59213/)

Comment: The answer is: whatever the inverse process is of whatever causes it to absorb all radiation incident upon it.

Comment: @RobJeffries So say for a hot iron rod that is glowing, does the bumping of atoms move electrons into higher orbitals or is it the actual vibration of the atoms as either way the uses the kinetic energy of atoms which gave it incident energy

Comment: It is the inverse process(es) of whatever you say causes it to absorb *all* light incident upon it (otherwise it isn't a blackbody). If your question is what are the dominant processes in a *particular* case, then that is a different one to your headline question.